# Get sectionid from artice Joomla 3

Tags: mysql, joomla3.3

After upgrading from Joomla 2.5 to Joomla 3 my custom module doesn't work anymore.
I got some Text from `#__sections` where my id was in `#__content` -> `sectionid`.

So sectionid in `#__content` is deprecated but I couldn't find any other solution to get the section from a article. Has anyone an idea?

Comment: So did you find any solution?

Comment: @NiravZaveri it's a very old topic now... I personally gave up - so this is deprecated for me

Answer (score 0):

```
   $input=Jfactory::getApplication()->input;
   if($input->getCmd('option')=='com_content' 
   && $input->getCmd('view')=='article' ){
     $db=JFactory::getDbo(); 
     $db->setQuery('select catid from #__content where id='.$input->getInt('id')); 
     $catid=$db->loadResult(); 
   }
```

as seen at [Get current article category ID in Joomla 3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22877545/get-current-article-category-id-in-joomla-3-2)

My personal test:

```
   <?php // Joomla 3.1
   $app = JFactory::getApplication();
   $catID = $app->input->get('cat_id');
   echo $catID; 
   ?>
```

Comment: I'm sry, but this is not the category I'm searching for! It's the section! In Joomla 2.5 there has been a sectionid in the article-table. In Joomla 3.x there isn't a sectionid. I have to say I upgrade from 1.5 to 2.5 and from 2.5 to 3.x.